# Why does using "constexpr" give primary expression error in codeblocks

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gcc6

I am getting expected primary expression before constexpr in codeblocks only. Is there a way to fix this? This is the code I am trying to test. I have set c++ 17 as the compiler. I am using GNU GCC Compiler.  GCC (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0. I am not getting this error in Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void testType(std::vector<T> &x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        //push string
        std::cout<<"String\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,int>)
    {
        //push integer
        std::cout<<"int\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    
    std::vector<std::string> x;
    
    testType(x);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'constexpr'
error: expected ')' before 'constexpr'
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `#include <type_traits>` to your code?

Comment: What is your GCC version?

Comment: @AdrianMole  yes I have tried it.

Comment: @alterigel  GCC (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Comment: After adding the missing `#include <type_traits>`, the shown code compiles without eny errors with gcc 10. gcc 6 is probably too old for full C++17 support.

Comment: Works as of GCC 7.1. Sorry, chum, it's time to update. If you can update. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/qq86eE

Comment: it clearly complains about a syntax issue if statement in c++ `if (expression) {}` try with  parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of GCC does not support `if constexpr`. Support was added in version 7.

You can look up which C++17 features are supported [on the GCC website](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17); the line relevant for this question is "constexpr if". There are a lot of "7"'s – and even one "8" – in the column for the first version that supports each feature, so you should expect C++17 support to be spotty with a compiler from the version 6 series (e.g. your 6.3.0).